# Datadog - Alert if a value reached a threshold for x amount of consecutive days

Tags: datadog

I've found this article from DD: https://docs.datadoghq.com/monitors/guide/alert-on-no-change-in-value/ but it seems to be the more simple case of no diff over a period of time.

But, how is it possible to add a condition?
More specifically:
Trigger an alert if a value exceeds x each day for 3 consecutive days.

I imagine this to be a combination? E.g.

- check if value exceeded x over a period of a day
  AND
- no diff in the past 3 days